# Is it professional to walk directly to manager or send a email

Tags: professionalism, manager, india

I work for a reputed multinational corporation. We have open work area with small cubicles (2-3 person per cubicle).

My whole team (me, my team, my manager, his seniors) sits very near to each other (1 or 2 cubicles apart). My manager "Bob" is very friendly and has a good professional relationship with the team.

Is it appropriate to walk to Bob's cubicle and talk about some issue/idea ( if Bob is free) and then send a email summarizing, or should I first send out an email of my idea and then follow up?

There are few instances where I raised some issue/new ideas which Bob liked very much. Bob agrees on the things we discussed and promised an action on that, but no action until I remind him again.

Edit 1:  For clarification, I usually first check if Bob is available on Skype and ask him if it is ok to have a quick conversation now (face 2face).

The thing I am worried is that Bob forgets to take action on them until I remind him. So I was wondering what is the best way to make sure that action is taken on things which were discussed (if he agrees to take action).

I am not sure(because I am new) if it is ok to send a email on things we just discussed.

My office setting is similar to below image.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

> My manager "Bob" is very friendly and has a good professional relationship with the team.

He's friendly and you hvae a good relationship with him - so just walk up to him and ask.

> Hi Bob, there's a few ideas I'd like to walk through with you at some point - when would be convenient, or would you sooner I sent through an email?

Answer (score 1):

The preferred form of communication depends on the manager.

Some managers have an "open door policy" (even if their cubicle doesn't have a door). They invite their subordinates to talk to them directly whenever they have some concern or request. Others prefer to be contacted in writing, so they can take care of things when they fit into their schedule. Ask your manager what kind of communication style they prefer.

When your manager tends to forget about verbal promises they made, then it can be useful to directly schedule a follow-up meeting. This creates a deadline for them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, **I** don't work very well with interruptions, and I too-easily forget things, so what **I** prefer is either an e-mail or, maybe better yet, a request to add something to my calendar.  But, "y'know, 'ask Bob!'"  What works best for him?

Answer (score 0):

I was agreeing with the idea of walking up to him, but looking at the cubical type setup you have, you may lose a bit of time walking over to his cube to find out he isn't there (this has frustrated me in the past). So perhaps prioritize using Skype, and pay particular attention to the status too.  If his status states "busy" only disturb him for an urgent issue.  Otherwise, if his status is available, I would ask him if you can come ask a quick question. I know, I kind of get annoyed when people ask if they can ask a question, but sometimes they are available but not at their seat, you know?